# Can I store formclass in array? (Delphi)

Tags: arrays, forms, delphi, code-duplication

My current code has lots of code repetition and I want to reduce it by using array so I can just loop thru the array and get the class form that I need to create. For each tabsheet created, it will create a form within it. This is my current code:

```
 var TabSheet := TcxTabSheet.Create(cxPageControl1);
 TabSheet.Caption := 'Page 1';
 TabSheet.PageControl := cxPageControl1;
 cxPageControl1.Properties.ActivePage := TabSheet;

 with TForm1.Create(nil) do begin
   Parent := TabSheet;
   Height := TabSheet.Height;
   Width := TabSheet.Width;
   Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
   Show;
 end;

 var TabSheet := TcxTabSheet.Create(cxPageControl1);
 TabSheet.Caption := 'Page 2';
 TabSheet.PageControl := cxPageControl1;

 with TForm2.Create(nil) do begin
   Parent := TabSheet;
   Height := TabSheet.Height;
   Width := TabSheet.Width;
   Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
   Show;
 end;

//and so on ...
```

So I thought of reducing it by looping thru an array so that I don't have to retype it again and again. Is there a way I could do this in array? Or do anyone have other suggestion. I tried declaring a `var fm: TForm` at the top then assigned it like  `fm := TForm1.Create(nil)` at each loop but this way, I couldn't access the methods and component defined in `TForm1`.

Comment: Btw, you can replace those `Height`, `Width` and `Anchors` setting with simply setting Align to `alClient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
type
  TFormClass = class of TForm;
  TFormDef = record
      FormClass : TFormClass;
      Caption   : String;
  end;

const FormDefs : array [0..1] of TFormDef = (
                     (FormClass : TForm1; Caption : 'Page 1'),
                     (FormClass : TForm2; Caption : 'Page 2')
                 );

var
    FormDef  : TFormDef;
    Form     : TForm;
    TabSheet : TTabSheet;
begin
    for FormDef in FormDefs do begin
        TabSheet             := TTabSheet.Create(Self);
        TabSheet.Caption     := FormDef.Caption;
        TabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;
        Form                 := FormDef.FormClass.Create(Self);
        Form.Parent          := TabSheet;
        Form.Width           := TabSheet.Width;
        Form.Height          := TabSheet.Height;
        Form.Anchors         := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
        Form.Show;
    end;
    PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Please also follow Tom Brunberg's advice to replace `Width` + `Height` + `Anchors` with a single `Align = alClient`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks for the reminder, I did followed Tom's advice